# Form not detecting dynamically selected /assigned values in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background Information:**

I have written some logic to copy a drop down box from location A on a page to a new spot within a table. 
I (attempt) to select a value from the drop down... and then later when the form is submitted, this value should be included in the form.

**Problem**

The form is missing the value from the drop down (called location_id). So using the code below as an example, when the form is posted, I should have "location_id=4"

**Jquery Code:**

This is the code that copies the dropdown list and attempts to select the right value:

```
//edit button handler   
    $(".edit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //don't submit the form <input type="image"> is also treated as submit trigger
            var location_id = this.id;
            var menu = $( "#location_id" ).clone(); //clone the global list
            //locate the associated "location_name" field for the selected row & hide the column    
            var location_name=$(this).parent().siblings().children("#location_name").hide();
            var row_name = $(this).parent().siblings().children("#name").hide();
            //replace location_name with the new menu
            $(location_name).replaceWith(menu);
            menu.find('option').each(function(i, opt) {

                    // OFFENDING LINE OF CODE???
                    if($(opt).attr('value') == location_id.toString()) $(opt).attr('selected', 'selected');
            });

            //change row name to input box for editing
            var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
            $(input).attr('type','text');   
            //$(input).attr('name','edit_row_name');
            $(input).attr('value', $(row_name).text());

            //replace exiting row_name with this new input box. 
            $(row_name).replaceWith($(input));
            //show save button
            var save_btn = $(this).siblings(".icon").show();
    });
```

By the time this code completes running, the GUI shows the right value in the dropdown list.  However, when I check the underlying HTML using the "Inspector" feature in Firefox, I can see that the "selected" property is NOT set.

So instead of something like this: (notice the "selected" attribute)

```
<select tabindex="1" name="location_id">
 <option value="0">-- NONE --</option>
 <option value="1">WWX</option>
 <option value="2">Canada</option>
 <option value="3">USA</option>
 <option value="4" selected="">NYNY</option>    
</select>
```

I'll get something like this:

```
<select tabindex="1" name="location_id">
 <option value="0">-- NONE --</option>
 <option value="1">WWX</option>
 <option value="2">Canada</option>
 <option value="3">USA</option>
 <option value="4">NYNY</option>    
</select>
```

But NYNY will be the value that's shown in the dropdown.  And when you click on the drop down, it does highlight NYNY in the list.

So it looks like the javascript code to select the correct item in the list based on the value is not working properly.
But I'm not sure what's wrong because it's "kind of" working.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what the table looks like before my edits 
http://pastebin.com/dXXFDrmd

And here's the html that's rendered after I add my custom logic:
http://pastebin.com/kxbU0fYZ

Comment: From my experience, that's typical browser behavior. It doesn't update the HTML to show the `selected` attribute, but it *is* selected.

Comment: The attribute slected isn't updated but the property selected is

Comment: @Stryner so how does one get the value to be set for the form submission?

Comment: Once HTML is loaded into the DOM typical changes to the page change the DOM, not the original html that got loaded.

Comment: @A.Wolff ... hmm... eventhough I've used the attr method?

Comment: What is with the asterisks after your attr("selected", "selected") line of code?

Comment: @KennyFellows sorry, that was my bad.  I tried to "bold" that line of code as I was writing this question... but when I didn't work, I just forgot to remove the trailing **.  So it's not a part of the actual code base.  Just typo in my question

Comment: sorry but I cannot see in the html the attribute `id="location_id"` you are using in the javascript. Where is it? Also. The new select is in the same page? In this case you have to give the copied element a new id since two elements with the same id cannot be on the same page

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is on the same page...with the same name.  but each row in the table has a separate form.  I know the code works because the original code has the same logic.  all i've done is add an edit button that allows inline editing.

Comment: I see my mistake.  when i substitute the text with my new dropdown, the new dropdown doesn't have a name called "location_id"

Answer (score 1):

The `selected` attribute does not get set automatically. It's rather used for preselecting an option. To get the currently selected option use:

```
// Get value 
$('#select-box').find(":selected").val();

// Get text 
$('#select-box').find(":selected").text();
```

From the jQuery [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) docs.

To select an option by value just call `.val(value)` on the parent.

```
menu.find('option').each(function(i, opt) {

    if ($(opt).val() == location_id.toString()) {
        menu.val($(opt).val())
    }
});
```

Comment: i might not be understanding your answer... but i need to set the value, not get.

Comment: Where do you want to set the location_id? On the second select form?

Comment: when the user clicks on the edit button, i copy a dropdown list into the row that was just clicked... and then set the button.  please see code with //OFFENDING LINE OF CODE comment

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do in the //OFFENDING block. It looks like you you are checking if any option matches the location_id and if so you want to select this option, right?